# Wildfly + Eclipse Deployment Scanners

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I'm completely new to working with servers in general and I am trying to set up some software for a class that is starting next week. I keep running into this problem while trying to get Wildfly to work through Eclipse. I go to run the server and every time, no matter what version I choose, I always get this same error message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Deployment Scanners for Server: WildFly 24+".
> Could not initialize class org.wildfly.security.auth.client.DefaultAuthenticationContextProvider

Here is the console log as well

```
19:43:26,466 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
19:43:26,474 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
19:43:26,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 24.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 16.0.1.Final) starting
19:43:27,102 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.16.1.Final
19:43:27,346 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) WFLYCTL0033: Extension 'security' is deprecated and may not be supported in future versions
19:43:27,542 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
19:43:27,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 16) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
19:43:27,614 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
19:43:27,629 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.8.4.Final
19:43:27,635 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.4.Final
19:43:27,665 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 24 IO threads with 192 max task threads based on your 12 available processors
19:43:27,669 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.health] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Base Health Subsystem
19:43:27,671 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCONF0001: Activating MicroProfile Config Subsystem
19:43:27,671 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.jwt.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYJWT0001: Activating MicroProfile JWT Subsystem
19:43:27,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
19:43:27,673 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
19:43:27,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following Jakarta Server Faces Implementations: [main]
19:43:27,686 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
19:43:27,689 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.metrics] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Base Metrics Subsystem
19:43:27,694 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
19:43:27,700 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
19:43:27,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.15.1.Final
19:43:27,717 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
19:43:27,727 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-00007
19:43:27,766 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.2.8.Final starting
19:43:27,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0009: Starting Jakarta Connectors Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.35.Final)
19:43:27,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
19:43:27,781 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.23.Final
19:43:27,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
19:43:27,817 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
19:43:27,821 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
19:43:27,892 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file 'C:\Users\USER\wildfly-24.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore' does not exist. Used blank.
19:43:27,894 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\USER\wildfly-24.0.1.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
19:43:27,934 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore C:\Users\USER\wildfly-24.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost
19:43:27,963 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 192 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
19:43:27,963 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 48 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
19:43:27,967 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
19:43:27,970 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) Queuing requests.
19:43:27,972 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
19:43:28,033 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
19:43:28,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0493: Jakarta Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete
19:43:28,188 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
19:43:28,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
19:43:28,198 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\USER\wildfly-24.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
19:43:28,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\USER\wildfly-24.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
19:43:28,220 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
19:43:28,267 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.4.4.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.10) 
19:43:28,329 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
19:43:28,331 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 24.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 16.0.1.Final) started in 2670ms - Started 319 of 558 services (344 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
19:43:28,332 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
19:43:28,333 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

I feel like I'm probably just missing something very basic here; as I said I am very new to this. The server *does* technically run, but without the Scanners I can't access any of the project directories.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm getting same error, not sure why :( I'm doing a new install of Eclipse and JBoss using Java 11.

Answer (score 20):

I also faced the problem while upgrading Java from 11 to 17. Researching for the root cause led me to [a discussion on google](https://groups.google.com/g/wildfly/c/_OuPrpsF2pY). It looks like some access restriction has changed since Java 11 and the problem can be solved by adding

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
```

to the `-vmargs` section in **eclipse.ini**.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this may be due to running Java 1.8 as your default Java install (i.e. Java 1.8 is what is first in your PATH environment variable).

I was able to resolve this issue by using the following installs

- jdk-11.0.11_windows-x64_bin.zip
- wildfly-24.0.1.Final.zip
- eclipse-jee-2021-03-R-win32-x86_64.zip

And then adding the install of jdk-11.011 to the beginning of my Path variable.  I was then able to reproduce the problem by adding a Java 1.8 version to my path variable.  For example, the configuration below gives the error.  Removing the first line resolves the error.

**This gives the error**
[image]

**This Works!!!**
[image]

**To ensure you are using Java 11, open a cmd window and type java -version**
[image]

Comment: The problem is not only reproducible with Java 8, but also with Java 16+. I did not test others (eg. 9-10 and 12-15). It does not matter what JVM the server itself is configured to run with but only what JVM eclipse is started with.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS for "Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.3".

Adding --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED to eclipse.ini as stated in @irieill reply fixed the issue for me.