# Error while trying to stop JBoss EAP 7.3 from Codeready Studio 12.19.1

Tags: jboss7.x

I am trying to stop the server from servers tab and i get the following error:

An internal error occurred during: "Stopping Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.3".
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.wildfly.security.auth.client.DefaultAuthenticationContextProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69462554/18090568.

My eclipse version is 2021-12, Red Hat Jboss EAP 7.3.
adding `--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED`
to eclipse.ini under -vmargs